# Create a symbolic link from inside the Android app's assets folder to its storage

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, apk, symlink

I'm working on an android app in which the user can play multiple Unity games. However, achieving this simple aspect has proven to be too complicated with Unity, if even possible.

After analyzing how Unity on Android works, I understood that it uses a bunch of libraries (called libmain.so, libunity.so and libmono.so), these three libraries refer to the code of the actual game which is stored inside the apk of the android app, specifically in "assets/bin/Data/" directory. The directory is hard-coded inside the code of the libraries, and everything in the libraries is legally prevented from being changed.

So, in order to allow the users to play multiple games, I thought that I could place the game that the user currently wants to play inside the "assets/bin/Data" directory, and so when the Unity libraries want to start the game, they will find it in "assets/bin/Data" and will start it. And then when the user wants to play another game, I simply replace the files of the old game in "asseets/bin/Data" with the files of the new game, and the Unity libraries will thus play the other game, and so on.

**However, this wouldn't work, because an android app is not allowed to modify its own apk.**

So, to solve this problem, I thought that I could put the files of the game to be played somewhere in the external or internal storage of the app, and then add a symbolic link (shortcut) to those files inside "assets/bin/Data".

That way, when the libraries of Unity want to play the game, they will go to the "assets/bin/Data" directory, where they will find shortcuts to the actual game in the app's storage, and since I can freely change the content of the app's storage, then I will be able to replace the game on demand.

My question is: Is it possible to create a symbolic link (shortcut) from the app's assets to the app's storage?? If yes, how??

If anything is unclear please ask me to elaborate

Thank you

Comment: Why not add a config file on the sdcard?  We do this all the time.  You can also modify this file as needed.

Comment: I didn't really understand how adding a config file would help me. Could you please elaborate more? :)

Comment: Assets are read-only at runtime. Use internal storage, external storage, or the Storage Access Framework for read/write content.  In your assets folder, you can point to a config file that can be read/written to during the run of your application.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to do this.  The assets included in the APK are not expanded to be on the device filesystem.  They are accessed in-place via the `AssetManager` APIs.

It would be an enormous security hole to allow an app to replace itself without the user knowing or bypassing the package installation path provided by the framework.  If all you need to do is push down asset type updates (graphics, levels, sounds, etc.) then consider using an OBB or other downloadable asset to extend the app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't think that would work for my case. I'm trying to build an app that is a mobile gaming platform with some characteristics. But one of the characteristics is that players can play different games made by different vendors on the app. So I need to be able to dynamically choose one of many games that are downloaded from the server. With the security restrictions this doesn't seem to be doable